# Sending HTTP Request with a file AND strings as post parameters using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I'm writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Application, In this app i need to send a request to the Sonic API server, the request should contain a access_id (string) a format (string) and input_file (mp3 file) , I'm stuck with putting both the file and the string in one request : this is what I've tried :

```
public async static Task<string> RequestSong(StorageFile mp3File, string responseFormat)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var webClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    var mp3FileByteArray = await readBytesFromStorageFile(mp3File);
                    form.Add(new StringContent(ApiAccessId), "access_id");
                    form.Add(new StringContent(responseFormat), "format");
                    form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(mp3FileByteArray, 0, mp3FileByteArray.Count()), "input_file", mp3File.Name);

                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await webClient.PostAsync(ApiAccessUrl, form);
                    //responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseString = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    return responseString;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle this 
        }

        return "";
    }
```

the request executes successfully but it says that missing or wrong access_id , access_id is used to access the sonic API and every user have a unique one, this does not work i guess because the parameters access_id and format are put in the request in a wrong content type(just guessing). because if i put the strings in formUrlEncodedContent, it works fine but i'm not able to upload the file with FormUrlEncodedContent.

Is there any way i can send the file and the strings both in the same request??

BTW it's System.NET.Http namespace.

Comment: Do you have a link to the SonicAPI? What are the protocols for the API?

Comment: Of course sir , https://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/analyze-tempo this is the doc of what i want to use in the API

Comment: See the sample url from the link you posted. https://api.sonicapi.com/analyze/tempo?access_id=584ee88b-4525-4f14-b2ea-94dedda17a30&input_file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sonicapi.com%2Fmusic%2Fburning_bridges_by_ueberschall.mp3 It seems that all parameters are passed in url.

Comment: Thanks for replying @EZI , Yes all parameters are passed in url, but how can I pass the file witch is loaded from wp storage ?

Answer (score 1):

Your access_id should be sent as a querystring parameter in your url.

```
ApiAccessUrl += "?access_id=" + ApiAccessId;
```

And remove the following line:

```
form.Add(new StringContent(ApiAccessId), "access_id");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about the file ? where should i pass it?

Comment: The same way you are doing it

Comment: With MultipartFormData the api says that input_file is missing , i'm pretty sure I should pass the file to by the URL

Comment: According to the API documentation, you need to use Multipart